# PHP MySQL Find event within range Lat/Lng

Tags: php, mysql, geolocation, geometry

I have a table that contains events and a location using MySQL `POINT(X,Y) as geocodedLocation` and I'm trying to use a radius search on this data now I have found what should have been the answer here
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31628/find-points-within-a-distance-using-mysql. I have seen this before and apparently this is Google's answer for using Locations Services

I have 2 areas that should be picking up events

```
Area 1 = `Array ( [0] => 51.524074 [1] => -0.1005592 )`
Area 2 = `Array ( [0] => 53.818391 [1] => -1.4714507 )`
```

I have some events

```
Event 1 `geocodedLocation` = POINT(-1.54907739999999, 53.8007554)
Event 2 `geocodedLocation` = POINT(-0.100559200000021, 51.524074)
```

Yes, I know the POINTs are the wrong way round, but I did not build this and I just have to use it.

Now this is the query I'm running

```
SELECT a.*
    ,(
        3959 * acos(cos(radians(51.524074)) * cos(radians((
                        SELECT Y(`geocodedLocation`)
                        ))) * cos(radians((
                        SELECT X(`geocodedLocation`)
                        )) - radians(- 0.1005592)) + sin(radians(51.524074)) * sin(radians((
                        SELECT Y(`geocodedLocation`)
                        ))))
        ) AS distance
    ,COUNT(*) AS pagedAmount
FROM Activities a
HAVING distance < 10
ORDER BY a.startTime ASC
```

As you can see I'm using the location `Area 1`, the event `Event 2` is at this location just a little more accurate but for some reason the query does not provide the result of `Event 2`

Comment: delete the count(*) as pagedAmound part and exchange select X and select Y since your point values are the other way around and you are good to go! the second event will be displayed when distance is bigger than 168

Comment: it is reversed i'm using Y as Lat and X as long. why would removing a count work?

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you want to count, if its the total amount of events then you have to put a subquery into your select, but if you want to count the amound of rows returned there is an php query for that like

```
$row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

you also need to include the group by clause to get more than when result if you use having and count in one query

```
SELECT a.*
    ,(3959 * acos(cos(radians(51.524074)) * cos(radians((
                        SELECT Y(`geocodedLocation`)
                        ))) * cos(radians((
                        SELECT X(`geocodedLocation`)
                        )) - radians(- 0.1005592)) + sin(radians(51.524074)) * sin(radians((
                        SELECT Y(`geocodedLocation`)
                        ))))
        ) AS distance
    ,COUNT(*) AS pagedAmount
FROM Activities a
GROUP BY distance
HAVING distance < 200
ORDER BY a.startTime ASC;
```

**EDIT**

a bit of digging in mysql revealed that the point object will store latitude and longitude as

```
Point(lon, lat)
```

so the original order like i did above gives you the right distances!

Comment: Framework i'm working in always adds count(*) for paging im not messing with the framework just building on top of it. as for that i tried your way first distance was miles off like i was getting a distance of 4976 thats out of the uk from my current location....

Comment: sorry, my bad your X and Y are right, but I'm still getting the result for Event 2 in my [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f000d5/3)

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar query in one of my projects. Modified to your specific situation this should be it:

```
SELECT a.*, ( 3959 * 
             acos( cos( radians(51.524074) ) * 
                  cos( radians( (SELECT Y(`geocodedLocation`)) ) ) * 
                  cos( radians( (SELECT X(`geocodedLocation`)) ) - 
                      radians(-0.1005592) ) + sin( radians(51.524074) ) * 
                  sin( radians( (SELECT Y(`geocodedLocation`)) ) ) ) ) AS distance
FROM Activities a HAVING distance < 10 ORDER BY a.startTime
```